# typescript errors when using headless ui documentation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, headless-ui

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Menu } from '@headlessui/react'

const MyLink = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
let { href, children, ...rest } = props
 return (
 <Link href={href}>
  <a ref={ref} {...rest}>
    {children}
  </a>
 </Link>
 )
})
```

Trying to use this snippet from headless ui react docs that suggest this for Next.js users. i am discovering that i get TS errors on ref and href. thoughts? Is this a case where i would needed to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

```
Property 'href' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2339)
```

ref={ref} error below this

```
(property) ClassAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>.ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> | 
undefined
Type 'ForwardedRef<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> | 
undefined'.
Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> 
| undefined'.
Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 
'RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
  Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAnchorElement | null'.ts(2322)
```

overall goal is to get keyboard accessibility headless supplies to work on my drop down

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, React.forwardRef takes two type params. The RefType and the Props Type (backwards from the function params, `(props, rev)=>{}`)

You'll need to pass the correct params like this. Though I'm relatively inexperienced at this, the RefType should be `HTMLAnchorElement` because that's what you're rendering within the link, and that's the type of ref `Menu.Item` is passing. As for the Prop type I'm less sure, but I beleve it's the `LinkProps` from Next.js and the default `HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>` as you'll need the href prop that's a URL not just a string from the LinkProps while you'll need the rest of the default anchor props as you'll be spreading them to the link.

[Here's a link](https://www.carlrippon.com/react-forwardref-typescript/) that helped me figure some of this out

```
const NextLink = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>  >(
  ({ href, children, ...rest }, ref) => {
    return (
      <Link href={href}>
        <a ref={ref} {...rest}>
          {children}
        </a>
      </Link>
    );
  }
);
```